# How to exclude property from swagger definition

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I'm using Swagger online editor. I create some model in definition

```
  Object:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      name:
        type: string
      some_variable_to_exclude:
        type: string
```

This is complete model and i use it in different responses. But in one of they i want my model dont present property "some_variable_to_exclude". How can i exclude it ? Is it possible ?
Okay, maybe not exclude, maybe some comment near property, but only for that response.

Answer (score 0):

In order to extend the Swagger Schema with custom objects, the field must begin with `x-`

See more here: http://swagger.io/specification/#vendorExtensions

For example, swagger-node uses `x-swagger-router-controller` to specify which controller to use for a particular API path. But you can use it for whatever you need, e.g., `x-custom-property`

Answer (score 0):

Create another definition without field you don't need

Answer (score 0):

Create definition without field you don't need, like

```
components:
  schemas:
   Object:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      name:
        type: string
```

then, on describe new full scheme, write this:

```
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            allOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Object'
              - properties:
                  some_variable_to_exclude:
                    type: string
```